# Android : BaseAdapter how to?

Tags: android, listview, adapter, android-cursor

Ok, I have been searching thick and thin, and I am having some issues implementing a BaseAdapter.

I have been able to implement a Simple Cursor Adapter 
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List7.html as per the example above.

There is a pretty good BaseAdapter example here : [List14 google example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html)

I am wanting to create my own List Adapter using BaseAdapter to show a listView, with multiple items from a Database. I know this can be done using the Simple Cursor Adapter, but I am looking to handle rows differently, so I want to be able to draw each row by overriding getView. The data would be pulled from a cursor.

I know this code is ugly for getting to the cursor data, but assuming I have populated a cursor. What suggestions do you have on this if column 8 contains the image resource id. :

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    cursor.moveToPosition(position);
    ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);
    i.setImageResource(cursor.getShort(8));
    i.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    i.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    return i;
}
```

Do you have any good examples of a BaseAdapter being drawn using a cursor?

Comment: Could you provide a little more detail on what you're trying to achieve / what's not working as you expect. What does the code you've shown do when you run it? How is that different from what you're trying to do?

Comment: Actually after a few more hours of digging around, I think I got it to work in some fashion. My biggest issue is if I delete an item from a row my listview is not updating, even w/ a mAdapter.notifiyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` from a method inside the `BaseAdapter` itself.

See the methods in [List8 of the API Demos](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List8.html) as an example.