# Setting space between different items of a listView

Tags: android, xml, listview, layout

I'm having the following problem: I have a ListView and I get the layout for its items from an xml file. The thing is, though, that there should be some space between sequential items which I accomplish by nesting my layout into a dummy RelativeLayout just so that I can set marginTop =" " to the layout containing the item. The problem is that when the user clicks an item of the ListView the whole area (including the gap between sequential items) becomes selected. How do I deal with this? Thanks!

Comment: Some code for us to work from would help you get a faster answer :-)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984313/spacing-between-listview-items-android

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of nesting items in a RelativeLayout, why not try using the listview's own "divider" to separate items?

In your ListView xml, add:

```
android:dividerHeight="15 dip"
```

(or some other value)

Comment: that along with setting a transparent image for the divider worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

try  this:

```
ListView android:id="@+id/MyListView"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
  android:dividerHeight="10.0sp"
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your own List View by extending BaseAdapter class in a separate class.
you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540461/android-baseadapter-how-to)