# Adding display settings to Android TextView

Tags: java, android, textview, checkedtextview

I'm working on a modified version of the Android Notepad tutorial. The following code is from the fillData function which basically displays the titles of all the notes on a table screen, slightly modified:

```
Cursor notesCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllNotes();
startManagingCursor(notesCursor);

String[] from = new String[]{NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE, NotesDbAdapter.KEY_SPECIAL};
int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text1, R.id.text2};

SimpleCursorAdapter notes = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.notes_row, notesCursor, from, to);
setListAdapter(notes);
```

The `notes_row.xml` file, is very simple:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

How can I add `@+id/text1` to this XML file so that when the `KEY_SPECIAL` field is set to true (or 1), the TextView is bolded? What if I want to use CheckedTextView and get the checkmark instead of bold? How do I write the XML file to look for that input to determine if it's checked originally?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write your own custom adapter to have text change based on conditions that are only known at runtime.  The Simple adapters work for putting a title and subtitle on every row, but if you need anything more than that you need to go custom.

Take a look at [Android : BaseAdapter how to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540461/android-baseadapter-how-to).