# Out of memory on a 10171204-byte allocation in android app

Tags: android, download, out-of-memory

in my app i am trying to download some video in button click. i am showing a progress bar in the notification area, i have already asked a question regarding this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102837/progress-bar-in-notification-area-is-not-closing-and-not-starting-the-second-pro) (it is under bounty)

Now to solve my problem i changed the code to be as follows, when the first button is clicked it starts an progress bar in notification by a class UploadService extends IntentService and the progress bar is shown

When the second button is clicked it tries to start another progress bar in notification by a class UploadService2 extends IntentService, but immediately the app gets crashed and it shows the following error as follows

```
E/dalvikvm-heap( 2325): Out of memory on a 10171204-byte allocation.
E/AndroidRuntime( 2325): Uncaught handler: thread IntentService[UploadService2] exiting due to uncaught exception
E/AndroidRuntime( 2325): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
E/AndroidRuntime( 2325):        at uk.me.hardill.android.notification.UploadService2$1.run(UploadService2.java:93)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2325):        at uk.me.hardill.android.notification.UploadService2.onHandleIntent(UploadService2.java:134)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2325):        at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:30)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2325):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2325):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2325):        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

My UploadServices class is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102837/progress-bar-in-notification-area-is-not-closing-and-not-starting-the-second-pro)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given that you're only using the buffer in this bit of code:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[10171188];
int len1 = 0;
while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) 
{
    fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
}
```

the answer seems pretty simple: use a smaller buffer. Even on a *desktop* I'd normally create a buffer of about 32K - creating a 10M buffer on a *mobile* device is a really bad idea IMO.

Even if you *could* fill that buffer, there's no need to have one that big - and as you're actually fetching a network resource, it's incredibly unlikely that even 1% of the buffer is ever going to be populated in a single read.

Comment: so how much buffer to be mentioned?

Comment: @SivaK: 8K? 32K maybe? I certainly wouldn't go above that.